Rig legs bending backwards
I'm trying to learn about rigging and ran into a probably common solution that I can't find answers for. See here.
I'm using the "chain" bone because I've seen it being used in a tutorial, but I probably didn't set it up correctly or it's not very useful here?

For more controlled bending direction of knee and elbow joins that bend only in one direction, usually you want to use an IK constraint on the shin bone in your example.
You would need to add another bone a short distance in front of the knee to be the pole target for the bend and you can use the foot bone as the target.
Within the Ik bone setting you have to set the chain length to two and you might have to change the roll of the bone if it doesn't work right anyway.
Here is a link to a short tutorial to clarify the process https://youtu.be/Pt3-mHBCoQk?si=zvWPnHeutMoMy8KK.
